# triggering a hover with jquery - suckerfish

Tags: jquery, triggers, focus, hover, suckerfish

So am trying to trigger a hover event using jquery, the jquery detects the element with focus and adds a class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').attr('tabindex', 0);
$('ul#main-nav li a').first().focus().addClass('hovered');
});
```

then the css declaration

```
 #main-nav li:hover  ul,  #main-nav li a.level1:hover ul,  #main-nav li a.hovered ul{
    left: auto;
    width:auto;
    display: block;
    top:55px;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;

    padding: 0px 20px 5px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-top:2px solid #fff;
    box-shadow:-5px 8px 15px -5px #000;
```

}

This should in theory work but maybe I am missing the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying for this:

```
$('ul#main-nav li a').first().focus(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
});
```